# Find matching columns between two CSV files

Tags: python, string

I have two CSV files containing the following header strings:

- file 1:

  ```
  Product invoice,product verification,product not completed,product completed
  ```
- File 2:

  ```
  Product invoice,product completed
  ```

I need to find the common columns:

```
    Product invoice,product completed
```

Please note that columns should appear in the same order both in file1 and file2.

Comment: can you add sample  input?

Comment: above is the sample i have two files of strings which are separated by comma and they are in specific order

Comment: I don't see any sample or code attempt for that matter.

Comment: @abd a description of the input is not a sample of the input

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and show us your attempts! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu

Comment: I read the strings of BPMN Labels through json in the text files like the one i mentioned above

Comment: @abd,  that is nice but you have not added any sample of how the strings look in each file. It is also unclear if you want lines at the matching line numbers or if a line appears anywhere in the file

Comment: What u understand from the above description@Padraic Cunningham ?

Comment: I each line the strings look like in above description and for each line i have to check in other file the sequence of strings

Comment: well are the delimiters the same, what are the actual delimiters, do you always have data in each column...

Comment: Yes I want to match the strings in same order

Comment: So only corresponding line numbers?

Comment: No for every line in file 1 i have to check all lins in file 2

Comment: @abd I've edited your question according to the various comments and what I understood of it. Please, review that edit and feel free to revert/edit further if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Make a set of  strings from each `row[0]` and `row[2]`  in file1 formatting exactly how it would appear in file2  iterate over file2 see if the line appears in the set:

```
import csv
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    # skip headers
    next(f1),next(f2)
    r1 = csv.reader(f1)
    # make set of strings matching format of file2
    st = set("{},{}".format(row[0], row[2]) for row in r1)
    # iterate over every line in file2
    # and check if the line appears in the set
    for line in f2:
        if line.rstrip() in st:
            print(line)
```

File1:

```
Product invoice,product verification,product completed
foo,1,2
bar,3,4
foo,foo,bar
```

File2:

```
Product invoice,product completed
foo,2
bar,4
foobar,foo
bar,bar
```

Output:

```
 foo,2
 bar,4
```

If you want the data in lists:

```
import csv
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    r1 = csv.reader(f1)
    r2 = csv.reader(f2)
    st = set((row[0], row[2]) for row in r1)
    for row in r2:
        if tuple(row) in st:
            print(row)
['Product invoice', 'product completed']
['foo', '2']
['bar', '4']
```

Comment: This code works when more than one strings are in between common strings @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: In output Product invoice,product completed should be present @  Padraic Cunningham

Comment: @abd, why? They are the headers how could they possibly not match? If you want to include them just remove the two next calls

Comment: Thank you @Padraic Cunningham I would be grateful to you.But if i have Product invoice,product completed ,product completed in file 2 then in output it should display product invoice ,product completed but it is not in output

Comment: This code does not work when i have two strings in between common strings

Comment: I know but if more than one strings are in between common strings then how can we do this?

Comment: again I cannot follow at all what your are saying, why is it so hard to simply add an example of what you mean to your question?

Comment: see in FIle 1 @ Padraic Cunningham

Comment: then get the fourth element `set("{},{}".format(row[0], row[3]) for row in r1)`

Comment: thanx @ Padraic Cunningham that helped a lot

Comment: @abd, no worries, for future reference, adding actual input and expected output makes a question much easier to understand.